# SSAS Cube Pointing to Empty Box

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

Here is a copy of my cube:

1. What effect does the black empty box have?
2. What is causing
       this?
3. How can I prevent this?

Disclaimer: I am new to SSAS and am trying to follow along in a book, but I am unsure in what I did wrong.

[image: black empty box]

**Edit:** Here is the `ForeignKeyName` when I click on the arrow pointing to the black box:

```
FK_Fact_Sale_Stock_Item_Key_Dimension_Stock Item
```

Comment: Looks like a glitch in the visual display. Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: I have already tried this :/

Comment: I am having the same issue. Using VS 2017. The blank box seems to be the same as a data table off to the side that is just floating there, not connected to anything even though there are many FKs. It doesn't seem to be causing any problems, but I have just started this cube.